# Yii2 yii.activeForm.js contentType: false

Tags: javascript, yii2, валидация, forms

Каким образом можно задать `contentType` при использовании ajax валидации? Разработчики фреймворка почему–то решили, что всем будет достаточно `contentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Мне же нужно получить `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` Сама часть ajax запроса фреймворка на валидацию выглядит так

```
$.ajax({
   url: data.settings.validationUrl,
   type: $form.attr('method'),
   contentType: false, // пришлось дописать напрямую, но это не выход
   data: $form.serialize() + extData,
   dataType: data.settings.ajaxDataType,
   complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
       $form.trigger(events.ajaxComplete, [jqXHR, textStatus]);
   },
```

Есть event ajaxBeforeSend

```
$(document).on('ajaxBeforeSend', '#w0', function(event, jqXHR, settings) {

    var form = $(this);

    var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

    settings.data = formData;
    settings.async = false;
    settings.cache = false;
    settings.contentType = false;
    settings.processData = false;

    console.log('ajaxBeforeSend');
    console.log(settings);

    return true;
});
```

Но как в нем дописать contentType хз, так конечно же не работает

```
settings.contentType = false;
```

Comment: Если вы уже сами ответили на свой вопрос сделайте это ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521594/using-ajax-beforesend-to-modify-data В моем случае, решение выглядит так

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: false
});
```